# I can't start presto service in AWS EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr, presto

I had a Spark job that was taking too long and was looking at running "top" jobs. I saw the presto service that was taking up a lot of memory and running for so long so I did

```
sudo stop presto-server
```

But then when I did

```
sudo start presto-server
```

it says

```
start: Job failed to start
```

Should I be worried?? How do you fix it? This is a production environment.

Comment: Can you send us the error log, usually located in `/var/log/presto`? No need for the entire thing, you should be able to see the log being generated when you try starting the service.

Comment: there's no presto in /var/log. Only 
hadoop-state-pusher  lastlog  oozie  tmp

Comment: That's strange.. What EMR version is it? Are you `ssh`ing into master node? Was Presto installed through EMR or manually?